# I want to make a cell's value change according to the value from another cell

Tags: excel, cell, calculation

[image]

I have an excel with the people that are working at a company, I have the cell C4, and its value represents the total number of workers, including those that are on holiday, the company sends workers to 4 different projects, the cells D4, E4, G4 and H4 represent the number of workers assinged to each project, and the same as before, including those on holiday. The workers are divided in

1. Those that are waiting for a project (D10, E10, G10 and H10); Total (C10)
2. Those that are on holiday (D11, E11, G11 and H11); Total (C11)
3. Those with a reasoned absence (D13, E13, G13 and H13); Total (C13)
4. Those that are currently working (D15, E15, G15 and H15); Total (C15)

If, I am to add more people on holiday, for example D11, then the amount of people working on that certain project should decrease, if I add one, then there should be one less in the cell with working people from that project, D15. But also the total of those in holiday and those that are working should change, if I add one in holiday, the holiday total rises, and the working one decreases. The most important condition of this operation, is that the total of all people that are into the company, C4, shouldn't change when the amount of those 2 cells is changing. So, the numbers that appear on every row, do so, as it stated previously, and the columns as well. The numbers inside the circle are depending on those that are pointed, if one of the values that are arrowed decreases, the one inside the circle, from the same column, shall increase.

I really hope I made myself clear.

Comment: I've upvoted your question, so your reputation has increased. Can you add a picture now?

Comment: @DAMGG, to understand, do every number in this spreadsheet have been entered manually ? Is there any formulas ?

Comment: At the moment, C4 is the sum of the horizontal and vertical numbers and then divided by 2. D4 is the sum of the vertical numbers, as well as E4, G4 and H4. C10 is the sum of horizontal numbers, as well as C11, C13 and C15. All the other numbers are entered manually.

Comment: The problem is, that if you move somebody to holiday, as far as I understood, you will always have to remove that person from another category, e.g. working on the project. But I believe hat may not always be the case right?

Comment: Well, mostly that is the case, like, if we add to those in holiday, it makes sense to take from those that are currently working, but, in a more special and unique case, we would also take from those with a reasoned absence. These 2, are the only rows where the amount should change, according to the other cells.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend modifying which values needs to be entered manually.

Entered manually :

- Number of workers on each project (D4 to H4)
- Number of workers waiting (D10 to H10)
- Number of workers on holiday (D11 to H11)
- Number of workers absent (D13 to H13)

Sums :

- Horizontal numbers : C4 to C15
- D15 to H15 : =D4-SUM(D10,D11,D13)

**Alternatively,** if you have a table that mentions for each worker on which project they are working and their status (working, holiday...), you should consider using a PivotTable

Comment: What is the purpose of the recommendation, like, how is it helping to enter more data manually, because I don't really get it?!

Comment: That makes the number of working workers depending on the number of workers in holiday or absent, and the number of workers assigned to each project. Assuming that you have to mark a worker in holiday more often than assigning a worker to a project, i think it would solve your problem. Otherwise, I dont see how you can make the number of working workers dynamic without using macros with, for example, spin buttons.